# Update Button Text on Tap Gesture

Tags: swiftui

What I'm trying to do, is update a button's label's text on action or onTapGesture. But I can't figure out how to get from back to update the button's label.

I get *Value of type 'ContentView' has no member 'lable'* for this one.

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Enroute")
}.foregroundColor(.red)
.onTapGesture {
    self.lable(Text(getCurrentTime()))
}
```

And *Value of type 'ContentView' has no member 'lable'* here as well.

```
Button(action: {
    self.lable(Text(getCurrentTime()))
}) {
    Text("Enroute")
}.foregroundColor(.red)
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Enroute")
            }.foregroundColor(.red)
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("On Scene")
            }.foregroundColor(.yellow)
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Leave Scene")
            }.foregroundColor(.green)
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("At Hospital")
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("In Service")
            }.foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Times")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

func getCurrentTime() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `onTapGesture` to a Button, the Button's `action` is called when the button is tapped.

For changing the label, you will need to modify your view's state when the button is tapped, and the `body` property will recalculate the views inside it to display the updated time.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var enrouteText = "Enroute"
    @State var onSceneText = "On Scene"

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                self.enrouteText = getCurrentTime()
            }) {
                Text(enrouteText)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Button(action: {
                self.onSceneText = getCurrentTime()
            }) {
                Text(onSceneText)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight, that has gotten me closer, @Natalia Panferova; I do still want the text to be default "Enroute" or what ever, and only update once I've tapped that button to display the current time. I can thankfully still interact with my watch though my PPE so I want to use it to time stamp where I am on the assignment so when it's time to write the Patient Care Report I have the times safely place somewhere.

Comment: I added one state for each button and I just update the state when I push it. Lol, nice THANKS SO MUCH FOR THE INSIGHT!

Comment: @MarkTomlin Sure, I've updated my example with 2 buttons and default text in them, is it more what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so, so much!